Fitting the initial term structure with short rate models
Setting
I am reading Section 3.8 in Brigo Mercurio. It introduces a "method to extend any time-homogeneous short-rate model, so as to exactly reproduce any observed term structure of interest rates while preserving the possible analytical tractability". The extension boils down to few simple equations.
The dynamics of a time-homogeneous short rate model under the neutral probability measure are:
$$dx_t = \mu (x_t, \alpha) dt + \sigma (x_t, \alpha) dW_t^x$$
where $\alpha$ is a set of parameters. The price of a zero-coupon bond maturing at time $T$ and with unit face value is:
$$P^x(t,T) = E_t^x \left[ exp \left( - \int_t^T x_s ds \right) \right] := \Pi^x (t, T, x_t, \alpha)$$
The definition of the shifted short rate is:
$$r_t = x_t + \varphi (t, \alpha)$$
where $\varphi$ is a deterministic function. It can be proven that the price of a zero-coupon bond maturing at time $T$ is:
$$P(t,T) = exp \left( - \int_t^T \varphi(s, \alpha) ds \right) \Pi^x (t, T, r_t - \varphi (t, \alpha), \alpha)$$
Finally, the model for $r_t$ fits the currently observed term structure of discount factors if and only if:
$$exp \left( - \int_t^T \varphi(s, \alpha) ds \right) = \Phi^\ast (t, T, x_0, \alpha) := \frac{P^M(0,T)}{\Pi^x (0, T, x_0, \alpha)} \frac{\Pi^x (0, t, x_0, \alpha)}{P^M(0,t)}$$
where $M$ stands for observable market quantities. It follows that the zero-coupon bond prices are given by:
$$P(t,T) = \Phi^\ast (t, T, x_0, \alpha) \Pi^x (t, T, r_t - \varphi^\ast, \alpha)$$
Question
Am I correct to say that the definition of $\Phi^\ast$ implies that we are fitting only two datapoint? In other words, that $\varphi(t, \alpha)$, and hence $r_t$, dependent on the specific $P^M$'s we are considering? My understanding is that, for each pair $(t,T)$ we want to fit, we obtain a different process for $r_t$, but we don't care about the process of the short rate, because all we want is to obtain prices for bonds that are consistent with the ones we observe. But if the implied processes for the short rate are not consistent with each other, which one should I choose to price products other than discount bonds with observable maturities?
